# asp.net mvc editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to get the `EditorFor` method also render the label and validation for a property like the `EditorForModel` method does ?

Now When I use the `EditorFor` method for a property (for example a string), it renders only the textbox.

**EDIT**

Arnis I tried it out and there some problems:

The extension method should be bound on the generic HtmlHelper class. Also returning string from the helper was causing encoded html.

So I modified your code

```
 public static MvcHtmlString EditorWithLabel<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> h,Expression<Func<T, object>> p)
 {
      return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("{0}: {1}", h.LabelFor(p), h.EditorFor(p)));
 }
```

But the main problem is it works only with if the propert is of type string.

When the property is Decimal,Int,DateTime an excetion will be thrown.

`Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Comment: I'm quite sure problem is elsewhere. Using same approach for ints, decimals, datetimes and custom types too.

Comment: Could be the problem that I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 RC (Razor)?

Answer (score 1):

I would create custom html helper (code is untested):

```
public string EditorWithLabel<T>(this HtmlHelper h, 
  Expression<Func<T, object>> p){

  return string.Format("{0}: {1}",h.LabelFor(p),h.EditorFor(p));
}
```

This can be achieved with [templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) too, but I think custom helper fits better.